# shell script about "cat <<- _EOF_"

Tags: shell, cat

The shell script is erroring with

```
line 6: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `_EOF_')
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
    cat <<- _EOF_  
        test:  
        1. test  
        0. test test   
    _EOF_
```

But it is right.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<- _EOF_  
    test:  
    1. test  
    0. test test   
_EOF_
```

Comment: If you had TAB characters at the beginning of the lines, you wouldn't have seen the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Bash manual:

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
>          stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing  delimiter.   This
>          allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
>          fashion.

That is, it will fail if you have indented these lines with spaces, rather than tabs.

Another invisible problem is that the termination word must appear on the line, alone, with nothing around it. The only exception is leading tabs, if you use `<<-` instead of `<<`. So, a trailing space on the `_EOF_` line would do this.

By the way, testing does show that Bash will tolerate a space between `<<-` and the termination word, but it isn't shown as allowed in the Bash manual. This might be a portability problem.

Comment: I'm sure I indented these lines with tabs.

Comment: @lzbferrari: You used tabs in your editor, but is your editor set to save them to the file as tabs, or does it silently translate them to spaces? Use the `od` or `hexdump` commands on the file if you aren't absolutely certain. Also, have you checked for trailing spaces on the `_EOF_` line?

Comment: Sorry,I did not carefully check.I think I needed to modify vimrc.

Comment: @lzbferrari: In the future, since you're using Vim, a quicker test is that Vim will let you type `/<Tab>`. That is, you can literally search for tabs, and it won't find them if they've been translated to spaces. You might have to save and reopen the file to be certain, but on a long file, it's quicker than digging through `od` output.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. After testing for your solution, I found that the "space error" only appears within some shell function but not all shell functions. BTW, I'm using bash 5.0

Answer (score 2):

The `-` option to a here document `<<-` suppresses leading tabs in the body of the document but **not spaces**.

So replace space with tabs then your warning messages will gone..

Example :

```
if true;
then
        cat <<- _EOF_
            test:
            1. test
            0. test test
        _EOF_

fi
```

[Reference Link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)